# Auth0 is redireting to my callback-url with an additional #_=_

Tags: auth0

I am using the auth0-service and I have observed, that after a user logs in successfully, **the callback-url is called with an additional string "#_=_"**

How can I turn that off? I have already searched the documentaiton at auth0, but searching for "#_=_" does not yield reasonable results

I even had to escape that string with backslashes here in the SO-editor, because it was beeing interpreted...

Comment: Hi, did you see my answer below from 2 days ago? Still an issue?

Comment: @arcseldon yes, still an issue

Answer (score 0):

Please can you offer more information - what library / SDK are you using? For example, what happens if you use:

```
https://{{YOUR_TENANT}}.auth0.com/authorize?client_id={{YOUR_CLIENT_ID}}&protocol=oauth2&redirect_uri=https://jwt.io&response_type=token id_token&scope=openid email&nonce=123&state=xyz
```

Just add `https://jwt.io` as an allowed callback URL in your client settings from Auth0 dashboard.

Bear in mind that for SPA apps etc, the tokens are returned using URL hash fragments - this is deliberate as only meant for Client side consumption - [see here for quick description](https://community.auth0.com/questions/868/redirect-coming-back-with-hash-fragment-but-not-fo). Mention this only in case you were confusing correct behaviour?